# Как создать основной класс, который содержит вектор с такими же классами и его наследниками

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

У меня есть главный класс `BaseNode` и несколько классов, наследующих его (`RenderableNode` наследует `BaseNode`, `UIElement` наследует `RenderableNode`, а `Image` и `Text` наследуют `UIElement`)

```c
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

#define NODE_TYPE_NODE 0
#define NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE 1
#define NODE_TYPE_UIELEMENT 2
#define NODE_TYPE_IMAGE 4
#define NODE_TYPE_TEXT 8

class NodeFreedException : public std::exception {
    public:
        char *what() {
            return ((char*) "Used node already freed");
        }
};

class BaseNode {
    private:
        std::vector<BaseNode> children;
        bool freed = false;
        static const unsigned short type = NODE_TYPE_NODE;

        void checkIsFreed() {
            if (freed) {
                throw NodeFreedException();
            }
        }

        void customFree() {}

    public:
        BaseNode() {
            freed = false;
        }

        bool isFreed() {
            return freed;
        }

        std::vector<BaseNode> getChildren() {
            checkIsFreed();
            return children;
        }

        unsigned long long getChildCount() {
            checkIsFreed();
            return children.size();
        }

        BaseNode getChild(unsigned long long childId) {
            checkIsFreed();
            return children.at(childId);
        }

        void addChild(BaseNode node) {
            checkIsFreed();
            children.push_back(node);
        }

        void removeChild(unsigned long long childId) {
            checkIsFreed();
            children.erase(children.begin() + childId);
        }

        void free() {
            checkIsFreed();

            for (BaseNode node : children) {
                node.free();
            }

            customFree();
            freed = true;
        }

        unsigned short getType() {
            checkIsFreed();
            return type;
        }

        bool hasFlag(unsigned long flag) {
            return (type & flag) == type;
        }
};

class RenderableNode : public BaseNode {
    private:
        static const unsigned short type = NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE;

    public:
        bool visible = true;
};

class UIElement : public RenderableNode {
    private:
        static const unsigned short type = NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE | NODE_TYPE_UIELEMENT;

        void customFree() {
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
        }

    public:
        int position[2] = {0, 0};
        int size[2] = {0, 0};
        SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;

        void changeTexture(SDL_Texture *newTexture) {
            if (texture == newTexture) {
                return;
            }

            texture = newTexture;
            SDL_Point textureSize;
            SDL_QueryTexture(newTexture, NULL, NULL, &textureSize.x, &textureSize.y);
            size[0] = textureSize.x;
            size[1] = textureSize.y;
        }
};

class Image : public UIElement {
    private:
        static const unsigned short type = NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE | NODE_TYPE_UIELEMENT | NODE_TYPE_IMAGE;

    public:
        Image(SDL_Texture *imageTexture) {
            changeTexture(imageTexture);
        }
};

class Text : public UIElement {
    private:
        static const unsigned short type = NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE | NODE_TYPE_UIELEMENT | NODE_TYPE_TEXT;
        char *text = (char*) "";
        bool isTextChanged = false;

    public:
        TTF_Font *font = NULL;
        SDL_Color *color = NULL;

        void setText(char *newText) {
            if (text == newText) {
                return;
            }

            text = newText;
            isTextChanged = true;
        }

        void setTextTexture(SDL_Texture *newTexture) {
            texture = newTexture;
            isTextChanged = false;
        }

        bool getTextChanged() {
            return isTextChanged;
        }

        char *getText() {
            return text;
        }

        Text(char *textText) {
            setText(textText);
        }
};
```

Каждый кадр я отрисовываю элементы при помощи **SDL 2**

```c
void renderNode(BaseNode node) {
    if (node.hasFlag(NODE_TYPE_RENDERABLE)) {
        if (node.hasFlag(NODE_TYPE_IMAGE)) {
            SDL_Rect rect;
            rect.x = node.position[0];
            rect.y = node.position[1];
            rect.w = node.size[0];
            rect.h = node.size[1];
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, node.texture, NULL, &rect);
        }
        else if (node.hasFlag(NODE_TYPE_TEXT)) {
            SDL_Rect rect;
            rect.x = node.position[0];
            rect.y = node.position[1];
            rect.w = node.size[0];
            rect.h = node.size[1];

            if (node.getTextChanged()) {
                node.setTextTexture(writeText(node.font, node.getText(), node.color));
            }

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, node.texture, NULL, &rect);
        }
    }

    for (auto node : node.getChildren()) {
        renderNode(node);
    }
}

// Эта функция вызывается каждый кадр
void updateEmitter() {
    while (!isEnded) {
        updateDelta(); // Обновляет время с прошлого кадра
        callEvent(EVENT_UPDATE); // Вызывает пользовательскую функцию
        renderNode(nodeTree);
    }

    endedThreads++; // Это проверяется после установки isEnded = true и как только endedThreads == числу потоков, очищает всё и выходит из SDL2
}
```

Вывод компиляции:

```
src\main.cc: In function 'void renderNode(BaseNode)':
src\main.cc:176:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'position'
  176 |             rect.x = node.position[0];
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:177:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'position'
  177 |             rect.y = node.position[1];
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:178:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'size'
  178 |             rect.w = node.size[0];
      |                           ^~~~
src\main.cc:179:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'size'
  179 |             rect.h = node.size[1];
      |                           ^~~~
src\main.cc:180:43: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'texture'
  180 |             SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, node.texture, NULL, &rect);
      |                                           ^~~~~~~
src\main.cc:184:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'position'
  184 |             rect.x = node.position[0];
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:185:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'position'
  185 |             rect.y = node.position[1];
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:186:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'size'
  186 |             rect.w = node.size[0];
      |                           ^~~~
src\main.cc:187:27: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'size'
  187 |             rect.h = node.size[1];
      |                           ^~~~
src\main.cc:189:22: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'getTextChanged'
  189 |             if (node.getTextChanged()) {
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:190:22: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'setTextTexture'
  190 |                 node.setTextTexture(writeText(node.font, node.getText(), node.color));
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.cc:190:52: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'font'
  190 |                 node.setTextTexture(writeText(node.font, node.getText(), node.color));
      |                                                    ^~~~
src\main.cc:190:63: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'getText'
  190 |                 node.setTextTexture(writeText(node.font, node.getText(), node.color));
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~
src\main.cc:190:79: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'color'
  190 |                 node.setTextTexture(writeText(node.font, node.getText(), node.color));
      |                                                                               ^~~~~
src\main.cc:193:43: error: 'class BaseNode' has no member named 'texture'
  193 |             SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, node.texture, NULL, &rect);
      |                                           ^~~~~~~
```

Я хочу получить переменные и функции класса `Image` и `Text`, но вместо этого я получаю ошибку из-за того, что в `BaseNode` нет этих переменных и функций

Я пробовал сделать `renderNode` типа `auto`, переделать `BaseNode`ы в `BaseNode*`ы (также `.` в `->`), проверить тип класса в `renderNode`, но всё равно получаю примерно такие же ошибки

Возможно следует как-нибудь изменить тип вектора `BaseNode.children`?

**Минимальный** воспроизводимый пример:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseNode {
    private:
        std::vector<BaseNode> children;

    public:
        static const unsigned short type = 0;

        BaseNode() {}

        std::vector<BaseNode> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        void addChild(BaseNode node) {
            children.push_back(node);
        }
};

class TestNode : BaseNode {
    public:
        static const unsigned short type = 1;
        int test1 = 5;
        float test2 = 1.23;
};

BaseNode nodeTree = BaseNode();
TestNode node1 = TestNode();
TestNode node2 = TestNode();
TestNode node3 = TestNode();

void renderNode(BaseNode node) {
    if (node.type == 1) {
        printf("%i, %f\n", node.test1, node.test2);
    }

    for (auto child : node.getChildren()) {
        renderNode(child);
    }
}

int main() {
    node1.addChild(node2);
    nodeTree.addChild(node1);
    nodeTree.addChild(node3);
    renderNode(nodeTree);
    return 0;
}
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
5, 1.23
5, 1.23
5, 1.23
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите, надо делать с помощью вектора *указателей* на базовый класс.

Comment: Я уже пытался это сделать и получал примерно такую же ошибку. Не подскажите как следует правильно сделать это?

Comment: Простите, но разбираться в огромных простынях вашего кода — просто нет столько свободного времени. Но сразу — вообще `vector<Base>` вы не можете поместить объекты-потомки, будет срезка.

Comment: Я добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример в 54 строки кода (около 20 строк, имеющих большое значение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseNode {
    private:
        std::vector<BaseNode*> _childrens;

    public:
        virtual unsigned short type()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        const std::vector<BaseNode*>& getChildren() const
        {
            return _childrens;
        }

        void addChild(BaseNode* node) {
            _childrens.push_back(node);
        }
};

struct TestNode : BaseNode {
    virtual unsigned short type() override
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    int test1 = 5;
    float test2 = 1.23;
};

struct TestNode2 : BaseNode {
    virtual unsigned short type() override
    {
        return 2;
    }

    const char* str = "Lol, it works!";
    int k = 15;
};

template <class To, class From>
To cast(From from, const std::string& msg)
{
    auto pCast = dynamic_cast<To>(from);
    if (!pCast)
        throw std::runtime_error(msg);

    return pCast;
}

void renderNode(BaseNode* node) {
    if (node->type() == 1) {
        auto pCast = cast<TestNode*>(node, "Expected TestNode as class with type = 1");
        printf("%i, %f\n", pCast->test1, pCast->test2);
    }
    else if (node->type() == 2)
    {
        auto pCast = cast<TestNode2*>(node, "Expected TestNode2 as class with type = 2");
        printf("%s, %d\n", pCast->str, pCast->k);
    }
    for (auto child : node->getChildren()) {
        renderNode(child);
    }
}

int main() {
    auto nodeTree = new BaseNode;
    auto node1 = new TestNode;
    auto node2 = new TestNode;
    auto node3 = new TestNode2;


    node1->addChild(node2);
    nodeTree->addChild(node1);
    nodeTree->addChild(node3);
    renderNode(nodeTree);

    delete node3;
    delete node2;
    delete node1;
    delete nodeTree;

    return 0;
}
```

Вам нужно что-то такое?

Comment: Компилятор выдаёт предупреждение *-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor*, но это можно исправить, если добавить `virtual ~BaseNode() = default;` в начало **public** в **BaseNode**

Comment: Но зачем добавлять переменную типа? Это сразу говорит о том, что надо попробовать полиморфизм и виртуальные функции.

Answer (score 2):

Вот примерно как делается [то, что вы хотите](https://ideone.com/kzMU8s). Хотя если вы захотите создавать объекты через `new`, надо будет принять соответствующие меры для освобождения памяти.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseNode {
    private:
        std::vector<BaseNode*> children;
    public:

        BaseNode() {}

        std::vector<BaseNode*> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        void addChild(BaseNode * node) {
            children.push_back(node);
        }

        virtual void print()
        {
            puts("BaseNode");
        }

        virtual ~BaseNode() {}
};

class TestNode : public BaseNode {
    public:

        int test1 = 5;
        float test2 = 1.23f;

        virtual void print()
        {
            printf("%i, %f\n", test1, test2);
        }
};

BaseNode nodeTree = BaseNode();
TestNode node1 = TestNode();
TestNode node2 = TestNode();
TestNode node3 = TestNode();

void renderNode(BaseNode * node)
{
    node->print();

    for (auto child : node->getChildren()) {
        renderNode(child);
    }
}

int main() {
    node1.addChild(&node2);
    nodeTree.addChild(&node1);
    nodeTree.addChild(&node3);
    renderNode(&nodeTree);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но что я должен делать, если надо определить функцию или переменную в одном из многих наследников BaseNode? Определять её в BaseNode, или можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: Надо работать *через механизм виртуальных функций*. Как в примере в ответе. Обратите внимание, что `print` — виртуальная функция, так что на какого бы потомка вы ни передавали указатель — будет вызываться нужная. Советую обязательно почитать про наследование и динамический полиморфизм...